# VHDL concatenate two bits

Tags: vhdl

I have in VHDL two std_logic_vectors with the same length (a and b) and need one "big" std_logic_vector, like "ab" (a has to bee the high part of the bit word and b the low part). Has anyone an idea how I can do this?
For example: Let be a = 11 and b = 10 then I want the vector 1110.

Comment: It's not clear where you're planning on using an aggregate. Useful Stackoverflow search terms might be *[vhdl] concatenate* or *[vhdl] concatenation*. Where evaluated in an expression or as the target of a signal or variable assignment statement you can also use an aggregate when the type is determinable from context. IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.2 Operators, 9.2.5 Adding operators (&) and 9.3 Operands, 9.3.3 Aggregates,  9.3.3.3 Array aggregates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the concatenation operator `&`, like so:

```
c <= a & b;
```

You can also concatenate individual bits. For example, to switch the two bits in `a`, you could do

```
a <= a(1) & a(0);
```

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what I need!